# Cannot bind Meta + Shift + Character

Tags: key-bindings

I am not able to bind Meta + Shift + any character.

I do not experience these problems with other key combinations (such as Control + Shift + Key).

Below is the specific case that I cannot get to work:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-Z") 'zap-up-to-char-backward)
(defun zap-up-to-char-backward (char)
  (interactive "cZap up to char (backward): ")
  (zap-up-to-char -1 char))
```

Comment: Maybe `M-S-<char>` is intercepted by your DE for its own nefarious purposes? It may be that Emacs never sees it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-S-Z` would mean Meta + Shift + `Z`.  But `Z` (uppercase) is itself what Emacs uses for <kbd>Shift></kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.

There's likely no key on your keyboard corresponding to `S-Z`.  That's why you say it doesn't work.

If you use `C-h b` you'll find your key binding listed OK. And if you use `C-h w zap-up-to-char-backward` you'll see that it says it's bound to `M-S-Z`.

The problem is that you have no way of typing such a key sequence with your keyboard.

`C-` is special, in that `C-Z` is interpreted as the Control character `C-z`, that is, ASCII Control Z.

---

It's unclear what you really want to do.  Do you want to bind keyboard key combination <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Shift></kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>?  If so, use `(kbd "M-Z")`, not `(kbd "M-S-z")` or `(kbd "M-S-Z")`.

Comment: That solved it -- thanks! I guess the `C-` case got me confused, thinking `M-` would follow a similar pattern.

Comment: Both `C-` and `M-` are a bit special, for different reasons: `C-` because of ASCII control chars and `M-` because of the use of `ESC` etc.